# How can the components of the metric in one chart be used to construct an endomorphism with "the same" components?

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems, semi-riemannian-geometry

For a chart $x:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, the volume form can be expressed as
$$
\mathrm{vol}_g = \sqrt{|\det(g_{\cdot\cdot})|}\ \ \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^n
$$
where $\det(g_{\cdot\cdot})$ is the determinant of the matrix representation of $g$ in the coordinates $x^i$. Calculation-wise, this works splendidly. However, formalism tells us that we can only take the determinant of endomorphisms (i.e. linear transformations) which are $(1,1)$-tensors. What I wonder is this: what is the endomorphism $\phi_{g,x}$ that is truly being determined in
$$
\det(\phi_{g,x}) = \det(g_{\cdot\cdot})
$$
I know that $\phi_{g,x}$ depends on $x$ because the matrix representation of $g$ under coordinates $x^i$ produces the extra factor needed to keep the volume form invariant, but I do not know how this map can be defined.

**Question:** What is the endomorphism $\phi_{g,x}$ that satisfies $\phi^a_b=g_{ab}$ and thus $\det(\phi) = \det(g_{\cdot\cdot})$ for coordinates $x^i:U\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: small nitpick: if you're working with pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, you really need an absolute value sign inside the square root.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$, let $g:V\times V\to\Bbb{R}$ be a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form and let $\beta$ be a basis of $V$. Then, relative to this basis, we can calculate the matrix representation $[g]_{\beta}$, and this has a certain determinant. To do this "abstractly", what we need to do is consider the basis induced isomorphism $\psi_{\beta}:V\to V^*$ (i.e the one which maps the basis $\beta$ onto the dual basis $\beta^*$), and consider the "flat map" or the "musical isomorphism" $g^{\flat}:V\to V^*$ defined by $g^{\flat}(v):=g(v,\cdot)$.

Then, consider the composition $\phi_{g,\beta}:= \psi_{\beta}^{-1}\circ g^{\flat}:V\to V$. This is the right thing to consider as we easily see that the matrix representation of *this* endomorphism relative to the basis $\beta$ (we use this basis on the domain and target) is exactly what we'd like: $[\phi_{g,\beta}]_{\beta}^{\beta}= [g]_{\beta}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\det(\phi_{g,\beta})=\det\left([g]_{\beta}\right),
\end{align}
where the determinant on the left is the "abstract" one defined for any endomorphism.

---

In the manifold setting, given a chart $(U,x)$, we consider the chart-induced basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right\}_{i=1}^n$ and apply the above construction pointwise at every tangent space to get the desired $\phi_{g,x}$.

Comment: Isn't $\psi_\beta^{-1}:V^*\to V$ the same as the isomorphism $\#:V^*\to V$ defined by the metric tensor in which case $\phi(v) = \psi^{-1}\circ g(v,\cdot) = [g(v,\cdot)]^{\#} = g^{\#}(v) = v$ is the identity map?

Comment: @CamWhite no it's not. $g^{\sharp}$ sends $dx^i$ to $\sum_jg_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ while $\psi_{\beta}^{-1}$ sends $dx^i$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

Comment: @CamWhite also, if you think about it in a round-about manner, the objects $g,g^{\flat},g^{\sharp}$ can all be defined in a completely basis independent manner, whereas $\phi_{\beta},\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ very clearly depend on the choice of basis, so even by this heuristic reasoning, you can see that there's no reason at all to expect $g^{\sharp}=\psi_{\beta}^{-1}$ (these are both isomorphisms of $V^*\to V$, but they're different isomorphisms, thus $\phi$ is not just identity). Said another way: suppose $\beta_1,\beta_2$ are two bases, then by your logic we'd have

Comment: $g^{\sharp}=\psi_{\beta_1}^{-1}=\psi_{\beta_2}^{-1}$, and hence $\beta_1=\beta_2$; i.e you're in essence saying that $V$ only has one possible basis (which of course is completely absurd).